# Error in C code I wrote for level order traversal of a Binary Search Tree using queue

Tags: c, queue, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I have used a queue to traverse a BST breadth-first.

The code compiles and runs. I get the right answer too. But, for the final node, the char repeats 4 times and then an error message follows. The error message means I have invoked free() with an invalid pointer. I am unable to debug this issue, any help would be appreciated.

**Output:**
F D J B E G K A C I H H H H double free or corruption (fasttop)
Aborted

```
//bfs - level order traversal - USING QUEUE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct bstnode {
    char data;
    struct bstnode *left;
    struct bstnode *right;
};

struct bstnode *front = NULL;
struct bstnode *rear = NULL;

struct bstnode *newnode (char d);
struct bstnode *insert (struct bstnode *root, char d);
void bfs (struct bstnode *root);
void enqueue (struct bstnode *root);
struct bstnode *dequeue();

int main (void) {
    struct bstnode *root = NULL;

    root = insert (root, 'F');
    root = insert (root, 'D');
    root = insert (root, 'B');
    root = insert (root, 'A');
    root = insert (root, 'E');
    root = insert (root, 'C');
    root = insert (root, 'J');
    root = insert (root, 'K');
    root = insert (root, 'G');
    root = insert (root, 'I');
    root = insert (root, 'H');

    bfs(root);
}

//create node
struct bstnode *newnode (char d) {
    struct bstnode *newnode = (struct bstnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode));
    newnode->data = d;
    newnode->left = newnode->right = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

//insert in bst
struct bstnode *insert (struct bstnode *root, char d) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = newnode(d);
    }
    else if (d <= root->data) {
        root->left = insert (root->left, d);
    }
    else {
        root->right = insert (root->right, d);
    }
    return root;
}

//level order traversal using queue
void bfs (struct bstnode *root) {
    struct bstnode *current = root;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", current->data);

        if (current->left != NULL) {
            enqueue(current->left);
        }
        if (current->right != NULL) {
            enqueue(current->right);
        }
        current = dequeue();  //remove char at front
    }
}

//enqueue children
void enqueue (struct bstnode *root) {
    struct bstnode *current = (struct bstnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode));
    current->data = root->data;
    current->left = root;
    current->right = NULL;

    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL) {
        front = rear = current;
        return;
    }
    rear->right = current;
    rear = current;
}

//pop element at front
struct bstnode *dequeue() {
    struct bstnode *ptr = front;

    if (front == NULL) {
        printf("there is no queue\n");
    }
    if (front == rear) {
        front = rear = ptr;
    } else {
        front = front->right;
    }

    struct bstnode *next = ptr->left;
    free(ptr);
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand your code 100% yet —
I’ve just been eyeballing it for about 20 minutes,
and I haven’t tried to run it —
but I believe that I see a problem in `dequeue()`. 
When you call it with only one node left in the queue (i.e., `front == rear`),
it does

```c
    front = rear = ptr;
```

where `ptr` equals `front`. 
So this line is setting `front` and `rear`
to the values they’re already holding,
and not removing a node from the queue. 
So the next time you call `dequeue()`,
the queue still contains the `H` node —
and you never unlink it from the queue, even though you do `free` it.

I suspect that you meant to do

```c
    front = rear = NULL;
```